# External access to RDS not working

Tags: remote-desktop-services

So I have an issue where I have setup a RDS environment:

All servers are win 2008 R2

RDS1 - Licensing, gateway, broker

RDS2,3,4 and RDS5 - Session Hosts.

All in a farm called Farm1.

I have a cert from a 3rd party trusted CA installed.

RDP file has the correct settings, as: 
Internally the RDP session to farm1.doamin.com using gateway sevrver settings of RDS.Domain.com works and I am load balanced to different members in the farm.

External DNS was setup RDS.domain.com to nat to the gateway server RDS1
Firewall rules allow https to the gateway server RDS1
However external connections fail with the error:

**"Your computer can't connect to the remote computer because teh Remote Desktop Gateway server is temporarily unavailable. Try reconnecting later or contact your network administrator for assistance"**

I cant find logs on any of the servers to tell me why its failing.

Any insight is appreciated.